# Where's the up-to-date C# spec already?

Tags: c#, documentation, specifications

Every now and then (usually when I stumble upon one of *[Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert)'s* or *[Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)'s* answers) I want to get a quick read of some section of the C# spec.

Problem is, the only *online* version I can find pertains to the [C# for VS 2003](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287560%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (i.e. [C# v1.2 / .NET v1.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29#Versions) ).

The [*current* version of the spec on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228593.aspx)  is only available as a `.docx` **[download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029)** which is less than optimal for a quick read and a complete misfit for linking to a certain part of it.

**Is there an online version** of the said document that I have failed to find?

Comment: Why don't you just use Word to convert the file?  It supports the .html and .mht format, you can open it in a browser.  PDF and XPS too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it's available online, but it's worth noting that the spec is installed as part of visual studio -e.g.

```
[prog files]\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC#\Specifications\1033\CSharp Language Specification.doc
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not *officially* available online, I've [looked around](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/45995/16761) for online document viewers.

**The spec (for C# v5) can be [browsed online here](http://www.docspal.com/viewer?id=nrlhoqkg-3454311).**
Note that it has 500+ pages, so it takes a few seconds to load...